# Routing troubles on secondary FIB/routing table on FreeBSD

Tags: networking, routing, freebsd, gateway

I have a need for a secondary routing table on this machine. I've got everything mostly set up, but I'm having an issue getting the default route working on the secondary fib.

In most information I can find about secondary routing tables, a simple eg. `setfib 1 route add default 10.0.0.1` (where 10.0.0.1 is the router on the network) is used to set a default route for the secondary fib. In those cases, 10.0.0.1 is an external router on the network, and is a static route. In my case, 10.0.0.1 is the machine where I'm trying to configure this. It is also the router for the entire network. If I add that route, I can't connect to outside sources as the routing table pretty much loops back on itself. For example:

First, a route default route is added (a route to 10.0.0.1/16 is already in place)

```
# setfib 1 route add default 10.0.0.1
add net default: gateway 10.0.0.1 fib 1
```

Pinging the router (which is the machine itself on the primary FIB) works fine:

```
# setfib 1 ping 10.0.0.1
PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.043 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.043/0.043/0.043/0.000 ms
```

But external sources cannot be reached - "Time to live exceeded":

```
# setfib 1 ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
36 bytes from this_server.my.domain (10.0.0.1): Time to live exceeded
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
 4  5  00 0054 24ce   0 0000  01  01 3f00 10.0.0.1  8.8.8.8

^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

A traceroute to the external source reveals the problem:

```
# setfib 1 traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 64 hops max, 40 byte packets
 1  this_server (10.0.0.1)  0.043 ms  0.036 ms  0.024 ms
 2  this_server (10.0.0.1)  0.033 ms  0.030 ms  0.028 ms
 3  this_server (10.0.0.1)  0.027 ms  0.031 ms  0.032 ms
    ...snip...
64  this_server (10.0.0.1)  0.132 ms  0.138 ms  0.137 ms
```

The public interface on this machine is on another physical port. If I manually add the ISP provided gateway which is assigned via DHCP, the fib works - though that's not a long term solution as the gateway can change. I'm aware I may be able to set up some sort of hook to re-assign the gateway automatically when provided with a new one, but I'd rather do this the clean and correct way.

I guess what I'm looking for is how to route traffic on that fib over the other interface, rather than over an IP? Is that even a thing? I honestly don't know enough about routing to really know where I'm meant to be going with this.

Here's an abbreviated version of the routing table on both fibs (some established OpenVPN tunnels and other misc things such as an ipv6 tunnel are omitted):

```
# netstat -r4
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags     Netif Expire
default            lo0-100.NYCMNY-VFT UGS         em0
10.0.0.0/16        link#1             U           re0

# setfib 1 netstat -r4
Routing tables (fib: 1)

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags     Netif Expire
default            this_server        UGS         re0
10.0.0.0/16        link#1             U           re0
```

I appreciate any help at all with this!

Answer (score 1):

Correct, you are adding yourself as the default route and this will not work.  You need to change the gateway to another host on the 10.0.0.0 network that will handle the routing for you.

Change the command route command to:

```
setfib 1 route add default <router on 10.0.0.0 network>
```

Then when you do `setfib 1 ping 8.8.8.8`, it will be forwarded to the router which is then expected to handle forwarding it on.